# How to use gridshift file with DotSpatial

Tags: dotspatial

I am trying to reproject from British National Grid to EPSG:3035.
Here's the code:

```
GridShift.InitializeExternalGrids(@"OSTN15", true);
ProjectionInfo source = ProjectionInfo.FromProj4String(@"+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs +nadgrids=OSTN15\OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb");
ProjectionInfo dest = ProjectionInfo.FromProj4String("+ proj = longlat + ellps = WGS84 + datum = WGS84 + no_defs");

double[] point = new double[2];
double[] z = new double[1];
z[0] = 1;
point[0] = 361820.25;
point[1] = 183768.60;
                
Reproject.ReprojectPoints(point, z, source, dest, 0, 1);
Console.WriteLine(point[0]);
Console.WriteLine(point[1]);
```

As you can see I've initialised my grids to the directory OSTN15.
It finds this directory fine, if I change the name slightly to something random it throws a can't can't find dir error so I know it is seeing the directory.

In my proj4 sting I then reference the file within my directory with "+nadgrids=OSTN15\OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb".

When I run this code my points are offset.

If I remove the 'Gridshift' code and the '+nadgrids=OSTN15\OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb' from the Proj4 string and run the code I get exactly the same result.

Also, if I just change the name of the .gsb file in my Proj4 string to something random the code runs without throwing an error so clearly, the gridshift parts of my code are not having any affect.
What else should I try?